# Do new badges take time to propagate?

Tags: discussion, badges, caching

I was recently awarded the "Electorate" badge.  However, for whatever reason, it has not appeared in the Achievements menu at the top.  Usually, these badges appear nearly instantly.

Here's the "Select your next badge" screen:

[image: See, I do have Electorate]

But here is my profile picture:

[image: But not on my profile]

Is there a reason it hasn't appeared, or is the answer simply "[because caching](https://xkcd.com/908/)"?

Comment: I would blame [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259626

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the answer coming from [Why is my electorate badge not showing up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259621/175248)

> The new profile tracker does put a checkmark on the badge once you
>   *meet the requirements*.
>
> *Awarding the badge* takes a bit longer, and, as far I can see, you've
>   got it. So once you see such a checkmark, you can be sure the badge is
>   already flying to you on the big wings.